# Magneto 2 logs me out automaticaly

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.4

I'm running Magento 2.4.4.

I'm facing a bit of an issue with Magento 2 backend – it keeps booting me out when I'm working with multiple tabs.

To put it simply, I'm tinkering with a few item cards simultaneously. When I hit the save button to store my changes, a spinning icon appears in the middle, and after a very short time, Magento gives me the boot from the admin panel.

This hiccup only seems to occur when I'm using, say, 4 tabs or more. I'm aware I could stick to a single tab or import info via CSV, but sometimes it's more efficient to make quick tweaks to 10 product cards open in separate tabs.

Could someone kindly offer some advice on what I should investigate?

Answer (score 0):

Increase session time out value. may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to extend the **Admin Session Lifetime (in seconds)** to prevent premature admin logouts. To configure this, navigate to the **Store → Configuration → Advanced → Admin → Security** section.

Within this tab, locate the **Admin Session Lifetime (seconds) field**, which is initially set to **900 seconds**, and you can adjust the time duration as needed.

[image]